# SQLite select from mutliple tables based on column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with columns id, product_type, product_id, quantity all as integer.
I need select data from another tables depending on product_type. For example. If product_type is 0 then select from tableA, if product_type is 1 then select from tableB etc. I tryied to find solution how to create select but unsuccessfully. Can someone help me please. I appreciate every help. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your post to include one of your attempts at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: More information. Please show the table structures and list what columns you want to see in the result set.

Comment: usually this indicates a flaw with your DB design when you need to do queries that dynamically select the source table. Show your full Database design and maybe we can help.

Comment: This question is not clear, You need to provide more information, if you need an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the master table with the individual product tables, but use a left join and include the `product_type = x` filter in the join condition so that only the desired records are actually joined.

This will result in many `NULL` values; use `coalesce` to get a non-`NULL` value for the output:

```
SELECT sales.id,
       sales.quantity,
       sales.product_type,
       coalesce(tableA.name, tableB.name) AS name,
       coalesce(tableA.color, tableB.color) AS color,
       tableA.numberOfAs                -- is NULL for other product types
FROM sales
  LEFT JOIN tableA ON sales.product_type = 0 AND
                      sales.product_id = tableA.product_id
  LEFT JOIN tableB ON sales.product_type = 1 AND
                      sales.product_id = tableB.product_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to turn that into a view which I could then do simple selects over…

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a CASE statement

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN product_type = 1 THEN (SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE ...)
      WHEN product_type = 2 THEN (SELECT column FROM table2 WHERE ...)
   END 
FROM table
```

Probably could be made more efficient by using JOINS but it would depend on your schema.

Comment: I think OP wants to select more than one field  from `TableA`,`TableB`   depending upon product_type in `table`, not just one field

Comment: Then more than one CASE statements.