# Join in SQLite with per-row selection of join table based on value in link table

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have tables as follows:

**muscles**

```
id          primary_synonym_id  source
----------  ------------------  ----------
1           1                   1
2           2                   2
3           3                   3
```

**muscle_synonyms**

```
id          synonym        
----------  ---------------
1           Gluteus maximus
2           Soleus
3           Infraspinatus
```

**sources** *(As you can probably tell, `sources` is intended as a link table.)*

```
id          type        sub_id
----------  ----------  ----------
1           url         1
2           url         2
3           book        1
```

**source_urls**

```
id          url
----------  ------------------
1           http://v.gd/3NCOMC
2           http://v.gd/fWdonY
```

**source_books**

```
id          isbn
----------  ----------
1           1405006692
```

From the above, which query would you recommend, to generate the following output?

```
id          synonym          ref
----------  ---------------  ------------------
1           Gluteus maximus  http://v.gd/3NCOMC
2           Soleus           http://v.gd/fWdonY         
3           Infraspinatus    1405006692
```

Please mention worthwhile alternatives - if any - to such a query, that you think would promote good database practice. (For example, a different way to structure the data and the use of a simpler query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unfamiliar with the `coalesce()` function. The following query was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988043/82216), and it works:

```
select muscles.id, synonym, coalesce(url, isbn) as ref
from muscles
join muscle_synonyms on muscles.primary_synonym_id = muscle_synonyms.id
join sources on muscles.source = sources.id
left join source_urls on
    sources.type = 'url' and
    sources.sub_id = source_urls.id
left join source_books on
    sources.type = 'book' and
    sources.sub_id = source_books.id
where ref not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont exactly understand what is  sub_id in sources and how its linked to source_books

sql will almost looks like this

```
select m.id,ms.synonym,su.url from muscles m
join muscle_synonym ms on ms.id=m.primary_synonym_id
join sources s on s.id=m.source
join source_url su on s.sub_id=su.id
```

Comment: The idea is that every unique source, whether book or URL, should have a unique ID. Currently, that is provided by `sources.id`. The other columns in `sources` (i) indicate whether the source is a book or a URL, thereby indicating which table to fetch the details of the source from (`source_urls` or `source_books`); and (ii) also provide the foreign key necessary to retrieve the correct row from that table. E.g. the source for the fact that the muscle `muscles.id=3` has the primary synonym "Infraspinatus", happens to be the source `sources.id=3`, which in turn is a book having ISBN 1405006692.

Comment: does the sql helps you?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Incidentally, before posting my question on SO, I had already written this query: `select muscles.id, synonym, url as ref from muscles join muscle_synonyms on muscles.primary_synonym_id = muscle_synonyms.id join sources join source_urls on muscles.source = sources.id and sources.sub_id = source_urls.id;` However, this query obviously completely ignores the source type and fails to get the correct source for `muscles.id=3`. It is quite similar to your suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any advantage in having 2 different tables for `source_*`.

I would merge `source_url` and `source_book` into `source_ref` so:

```
id          type        ref
----------  ----------  ------------------
1           url         http://v.gd/3NCOMC
2           url         http://v.gd/fWdonY
3           book        1405006692
```

And `sources` will become a two table join:

```
id          ref_id
----------  ----------
1           1
2           2
3           3
```

So you query will become simple joins as:

```
SELECT muscles.id, muscle_synonyms.synonym, source_ref.ref FROM muscles
LEFT JOIN muscle_synonyms ON muscles.id=muscle_synonyms.id
LEFT JOIN source ON muscles.source=source.id
LEFT JOIN source_ref ON source.ref_id=source_ref.id;
```

This will include all muscles, including those without `synonym` neither sources, neither any ref for source.

Comment: Thanks, but keeping source_books & source_urls separate will allow those two tables to be expanded with columns appropriate to citation conventions for their respective media.

Comment: That's just one suggestion. Indeed, you can add extra columns in a different table, refering `id` from `source_ref`. IMO, your `sources` table just doesn't seam to be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).